# modified-Flag for QAbstractSpinBox (QDoubleSpinBox, QSpinBox)

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

In `QLineEdit` there is an property `modified` which is set by QT, when the user changes the text of the widget.
Is there something like this for an `QAbstractSpinBox`?

When I'm trying to implement it on my own (with a derived class from `QDoubleSpinBox`) I can not be sure to reset the flag, because `QDoubleSpinBox::setValue(double)` isn't virtual. The signal `valueChanged` is emitted, when the user changes the value but also when it is changed by `setValue` or something. So I have no idea how to determine a programatly reset of the value.